# Why do upserted INSERTED.ID and DELETED.ID both contain values after MERGE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Surprisingly, I can't find an answer to this on Google, although my terminology may be off.  I also didn't see an explanation on [MDSN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql).

Take the following code to perform a simple `MERGE`:

```
DECLARE @tbl_1 TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), person nvarchar(20));
DECLARE @tbl_2 TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), person nvarchar(20));   
INSERT INTO @tbl_1 (person) VALUES ('Bob'),('Ted'),('Brian');
INSERT INTO @tbl_2 (person) VALUES ('Bob'),('Ted'),('Peter');

MERGE INTO  
    @tbl_2 as tgt
USING 
    @tbl_1 as src
ON
    (tgt.person = src.person)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET tgt.person = src.person
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (person) VALUES (src.person)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
OUTPUT 
    $ACTION,
    DELETED.ID,
    DELETED.person AS PersonOld,
    INSERTED.ID,
    INSERTED.person AS PersonNew;
```

In the results, I see that the ID value of each row is shown against both `INSERTED` and `DELETED` rows, where an `UPDATE` has taken place:

[image: Post-merge]

Why is this please?  I would expect `DELETED.ID` to be `NULL` after an update, with `INSERTED.ID` representing the *UPSERTED* row (I have worked with triggers in the past, and assumed `MERGE` would follow the same approach).

Comment: Why would you expect `DELETED.ID` to be `NULL` for the updated rows? `INSERTED.ID` is the same as `DELETED.ID`, both comes from the updated row, pretty much the same as with an update trigger.

Comment: Change the identity declaration for `@tbl_2` to `IDENTITY(10,1)` and see if that makes it any clearer for you.

Comment: I expected it because of the term *upsert*.  I didn't realise that under the hood, it was *delsert* for updates, so never realised that deleted row data would factor into the merge operation.

Comment: @EvilDr Have a look at my answer again, I added some updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `MERGE` as you seem to be aware is an `UPSERT` (update + insert).

Now, the `INSERTED` tables record information for rows added by `INSERT` & `UPDATE` comands and the `DELETED` table contains information for rows that were either updated or deleted.

Taking a look at the [MSDN documentation on how to "Use the inserted and deleted Tables"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables):

> The **inserted** table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT
>   and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new
>   rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The
>   rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger
>   table.

and

> **An update transaction** is similar to a delete operation followed by an
>   insert operation; the old rows are copied to the deleted table first,
>   and then the new rows are copied to the trigger table and to the
>   inserted table.

---

**Update:**

I saw you commented to your question that you realized that the operation is actually a *delsert* under the hood. And you might be thinking why would that be?

Think about how data is stored in SQL Server. It's stored on 8KB pages and when you update information in a column that is contained in a data page, the entire data page is being re-written, so essentially a ***delsert***.

And the same thing with an `INSERT`, a new row will go in a data page (and might generate a page split - but that's another subject) and that entire data page will have to be re-written.